# Keyboard Hook problems

Tags: c++, winapi, input, keyboard, hook

I am doing a voice chat application which uses a push-to-talk key. I have done a hook so it will register push-to-talk outside application too.

```
HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,(HOOKPROC)pushtotalk,0,0);



LRESULT CALLBACK pushtotalk(int key, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) {
if (key < 0) {
    return (CallNextHookEx(hook,key,wParam,lParam));
}
else if (connected) {
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* kbdll  = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    if (kbdll ->vkCode == 75 && wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        MessageBox(mainhWnd,"KEYSTART","KEYSTART",0);
    }
    else if (kbdll ->vkCode == 75 && wParam == WM_KEYUP) {
        MessageBox(mainhWnd,"KEYSTOP","KEYSTOP",0);

    }
}

return (CallNextHookEx(hook,key,wParam,lParam));
}
```

Problems;

1) Sometimes, (for example the first execution of the proc in the application), the proc causes a 5 sec system freeze before continuing. Why?

2) The hook only works on process that were started before my application started, if I start a text program after starting my application, the hooks wont register. Is there a fix for this?

3) If I hold down the key for ~3 seconds, alot of MessageBoxes shows obviously, but after that, the proc will never register another key being pushed down, so I guess I somehow gets disconnected from the hook chain?

Cheers

EDIT: Here's the main message loop for the application

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
switch(message) {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
            case ID_MENU_EXIT:
                SendMessage(hWnd,WM_CLOSE,0,0);
                break;

            case ID_MENU_PREFERENCES:
                voiceManager->send((void*) "1");
                break;

            case ID_BUTTON_CONNECT:
                onConnect(hWnd);
                break;

            case ID_BUTTON_DISCONNECT:
                onDisconnect(hWnd);
                break;

            case ID_BUTTON_SEND:
                onSendText(hWnd);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        break;
    case SOCKET_TCP:
        switch (lParam) {
            case FD_READ:
                {
                // Disable repeated FD_READ call while we process message 
                WSAAsyncSelect(wParam,hWnd,SOCKET_TCP,   FD_WRITE | FD_ACCEPT  | FD_CLOSE);

                // first four bytes is packet size
                // second four bytes are used to identify type of msg
                char* psize = (char*)malloc(5);
                char* ptype = (char*)malloc(5);
                psize[4] = '\0';
                ptype[4] = '\0';

                recv(wParam,psize,4,0);
                recv(wParam,ptype,4,0);

                // allocate memory for the buffer 
                int size_to_recv = atoi(psize);      
                char* textbuff = (char*)malloc(size_to_recv);

                // receive 
                int i = size_to_recv;
                while (i > 0) {
                    int read = recv(wParam,textbuff,i,0);
                    i = i - read;
                }

                // handle msg depending on type
                switch(identifyMsg(ptype)) {
                    case 1:
                        // handle 'text' msg
                        onReadText(hWnd,textbuff);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        // handle 'name' msg
                        onReadName(hWnd,textbuff);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        // handle 'list' msg
                        onReadList(hWnd,textbuff);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        // handle 'remv' msg
                        onReadRemv(hWnd,textbuff,size_to_recv);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        // handle 'ipad' msg -- add ip
                        voiceManager->addParticipant(inet_addr(textbuff));
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        // handle 'iprm' msg -- remove ip 
                        voiceManager->removeParticipant(inet_addr(textbuff));
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                // re-enable FD_READ
                WSAAsyncSelect(wParam,hWnd,SOCKET_TCP,   FD_WRITE | FD_ACCEPT | FD_READ | FD_CLOSE);

                // free resources
                free(psize);
                free(ptype);
                free(textbuff);
                break;
                }

            case FD_WRITE:
                break;

            case FD_CONNECT:
                break;

            case FD_CLOSE:
                onDisconnect(hWnd);
                break;

            default:
            break;
        }
        break;



    case WM_PAINT:
        paintText(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        shutdownConnection(hWnd);
        // reset window procs
        SetWindowLong(GetDlgItem(hWnd,ID_EDIT_SEND), GWL_WNDPROC,(LONG) OriginalEditProc);
        SetWindowLong(GetDlgItem(hWnd,ID_EDIT_IP), GWL_WNDPROC,(LONG) OriginalEditProc);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;

    default:
        break;
}


return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


LRESULT CALLBACK sendEditProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
if (message == WM_CHAR) {
    if (wParam == VK_RETURN) {
        onSendText(GetParent(hWnd));
        return 0;
    }
}
if (message == WM_KEYUP || message == WM_KEYDOWN) {
    if (wParam == VK_RETURN) {
        return 0;
    }
}
return CallWindowProc(OriginalEditProc, hWnd, message, wParam,lParam);
}
```

Where sendEditProc is a sub/superclass designed to intercept 'enter' keys when inside an edit control 'send'
Does this help?

Here's the message loop; it's the standard so nothing fancy that could go wrong afaik :)

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL,0,0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Comment: No, as I used WH_KEYBOARD_LL I placed the proc inside the main application.

Comment: If you comment out the MessageBox calls (or replace it with something like MessageBeep), do you still have the same problems?

Comment: Yes, the same problems occur again

Comment: Please edit your question to include the message loop for your application.  (If you don't have one, that may be the problem.)  I don't see anything jump out at me in the code you have posted -- the message loop could help to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Alright I've done it, any ideas?

Comment: That's not the message loop.  That's the window proc.  The message loop is the piece of code with DispatchMessage and GetMessage/PeekMessage.

Comment: Yeah, you're right -- not much can go wrong in that message loop.  In my experience, a delay of a few seconds (problem #1) has been caused by the message loop not running, and I figured it only happened the first time since MessageBox runs its own modal message loop internally, so the first message box would have "fixed" the problem.  Moreover, since MessageBox wasn't returning, it might have filled up a queue of pending keyboard messages or something like that.  But if problems #1 and #3 still happen without introducing a modal message loop and using the above code, I'm at a loss.  Sorry.

Comment: Stumbled upon this this morning - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2010/10/14/global-hooks-getting-lost-on-windows-7.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling CallNextHookEx one too many times. If `key < 0 return CallNextHookEx`, otherwise `return 0`.

The problem you're seeing has to do with keyboard repeats and the MessageBox or MessageBeep methods being very, very expensive calls. Try this test:

```
HHOOK hHook;
BOOL bTalkEnabled = FALSE;

LRESULT CALLBACK pushtotalk(int key, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (key < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(hHook, key, wParam, lParam);

    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* kbdll  = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    if (kbdll->vkCode == VK_F11)
    {
        BOOL bStarted = FALSE;
        BOOL bStopped = FALSE;

        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            if (!bTalkEnabled)
            {
                bStarted = TRUE;
                bTalkEnabled = TRUE;
            }
        }
        else if (wParam == WM_KEYUP)
        {
            if (bTalkEnabled)
            {
                bStopped = TRUE;
                bTalkEnabled = FALSE;
            }
        }

        if (bStarted)
            OutputDebugString(L"Pushed\r\n");
        if (bStopped)
            OutputDebugString(L"Released\r\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can monitor the debug strings by running the app under the debugger (check the Output window), or you can get [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) and watch that.

Notice that I do not check for `connected` as you did. You don't want to perform that check in the hook, do that outside the hook and only use the hook to determain if the key is pressed or not pressed.

Comment: How would I check for 'connected' and not use the hook if its set false? Do you mean to create the hook upon Connected and delete it upon Disconnected for example? Also, if I return 0 as you did at the end of the proc, dosn't that 'intercept' the key press messages and hinder them from being sent to the application which currently had focus? For example, if I write "k" in a text editor while my program was running, I want to catch the "k" but I also don't want to interfere with the output of the texteditor. CallNextHook passes the message along to the actuall guy who it was destined for right?

Comment: You need to know the state of the push-to-talk key (down or up). Do that in the handler as I've done here. You'll likely want to do something other than `OutputDebugString` in response and that code can check the connected state.

Comment: As for `CallNextHookEx`, you are correct. I got my hook handlers confused. You had it correct the first time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985.aspx

Comment: I understand that if I press the button for a long period of time, all the messageboxes/messagebeeps would become expensive and choke the system(hence the use of a global bool variables as you mentioned), but it does not explain why the first, short keypress produces that 5 seconds freeze in the system. Any ideas?

Comment: Your system sucks? It doesn't happen on mine. There is a brief, noticable pause as the hook becomes active, but it's nowhere near 5 seconds.

Comment: Does not make sense. Firstly, the the registeration of the hook is finished and the hook is active before the keypress, and secondly my system is not old. Ill just hope it dosnt reprodce for other clients.

Comment: The hook code doesn't actually "get hooked up" until the first event the hook monitors happens. In this case it's a keyboard event. I don't have all the details, but SetWindowsHookEx seems to do little more than "add a post-it note" in the kernel.